# type 'List<DocumentSnapShot>' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show the List when getting the data from the firestore.

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection("messages")
          .document(groupChatId)
          .collection(groupChatId)
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(20)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red)));
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                buildItem(index, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
            reverse: true,
            controller: listScrollController,

          );
```

I can successfully post the data in the firestore but dont know why i can't retreive it

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with this line

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.documents,
```

try

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.length
```

itemCount is as it sounds, the number of items to appear in your list, the parameter requires an int not an object

Comment: itemCount: snapshot.data.length this does not solved my issue i just made a mistake it should be  snapshot.data.documents.length.Anyway Thanks!